# Parameters passed to a function does not works as intended

Tags: python, function, tkinter, parameters, pack

When the "view" button is pressed, it should trigger the function solution(i) such that label should be displayed in the new window. The problem is that the window opens and the previous label is packed but the label which gets it's text from "i" does not gets packed, Is there any issue in passing the parameter.
Any help is appreciated.

```
root = Tk()
    root.config(background = "#303939")
    root.state('zoomed')
    def pre():
        with open("DoubtSolution.txt","r+") as f:
            dousol = f.read()
            dousol_lst = dousol.split("`")
        k = 0
        window = Tk()
        window.config(background = "#303939")
        window.state('zoomed')
        predoubt = Label(window,
                         text="Previous Doubts",
                         fg="Cyan",
                         bg="#303939",
                         font="Helvetica 50 bold"
                         ).grid(row=0, column=1)
        def solution(text):
            print(text)
            window1 = Tk()
            window1.config(background="#303939")
            window1.state('zoomed')
            sol = Label(window1,
                        text=text[:text.find("~")],
                        font=font.Font(size=20),
                        bg="#303939",
                        fg="Cyan")
            sol.pack()
            window1.mainloop()

        for i in dousol_lst:

            if i[-5:] == admno:
                doubt = Label(window, text=i[i.find("]]")+2:i.find("}}}}")], font=font.Font(size=20), bg="#303939",
                            fg="Cyan")
                doubt.grid(row=2+k, column=1, pady=10)
                view = Button(
                    master=window,
                    text="View", font=font.Font(size=15, family="Helvetica"),
                    activebackground="White",
                    bg="Teal",
                    bd=0.8,
                    fg="White",
                    command = lambda k = k:solution(i)
                )
                view.grid(row=2+k, column=2, padx=20)
                k=k+1

        window.mainloop()

    previous = Button(
        master=root,
        text="Previous Doubts", font="Helvetica 22 bold",
        activebackground="White",
        bg="Teal",
        bd=0.8,
        fg="White",
        command = pre
    ).grid(row=4, column=3, padx=20)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you copy/paste your code, it doesn't run, there are errors. Even after adding the imports, it complains about `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`. If you want to get help, you should ensure that the code you post can be run, so we reproduce your issue.

Comment: Now I have edited it... Hope it runs now.

Comment: We wont be able to run this without 'DoubtSolution.txt'

Comment: Here `command = lambda k = k:solution(i)`, why are you defining `k` but then passing `i`, either it is `command=lambda k=k: solution(k)` or it is `command=lambda i=i: solution(i)`.